# How to extend standard spring cloud data flow components and add our custom logic

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking to develop a custom processor that leverages the functionality of s3-sink and then add some custom logic to it.

I could do it without using standard components. i.e. using S3 APIs to write files along with custom logic. I would like to know if there is any way I can leverage the functionality of standard component and extend it to add our custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke some logic before or after the S3Sink normal logic then you can use [function composition](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/function-composition/#function-composition) and create a custom Sink application that imports the `S3SinkConfiguration` and defines a `java.util.Function` that is applied after the normal S3Sink logic.
You will need to set the `spring.cloud.function.definition` property to `s3Consumer|myCustomLogicFunctionName`.

However, if you want to tweak what the S3Sink logic actually is (not before or after it executes), you will have to look into what it offers for extensibility/configurability. The S3Sink app looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ org.springframework.cloud.fn.consumer.s3.AwsS3ConsumerConfiguration.class })
public class S3SinkKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(S3SinkKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see its just a SpringBoot app that imports a single configuration class. All the logic/magic is in that configuration. It in turn leverages [Spring Integration AWS](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws) `S3MessageHandler`.

What does the custom logic need to do? Maybe the underlying S3MessageHandler supports that via configuration/extension.

Comment: Thank you unobc, I'll will try function composition. We need to call another API to update the file location after file gets uploaded successfully

Comment: Hi onobc, I have gone through the documentation on function composition. I understand that I can only add a custom function before the Sink logic, not after the Sink logic. as per the documentation - "for a Sink instance, the function is applied before the sink's input". I need to update the file location after file gets uploaded successfully on S3, I should not update if there is any issue in uploading the file to S3. We are using fan-out approach for now to update file location using another component.

Comment: Though function composition eliminates the need to have another component, but doesn't exactly serve the purpose.

Comment: Hi @VenuGopal, I believe it orders them that way by default but you should be able to control order via `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition`. 

From above "You will need to set the `spring.cloud.function.definition` property to `s3Consumer|myCustomLogicFunctionName`"

From the docs:  "Spring Cloud Stream has a property called spring.cloud.stream.function.definition. It takes a pipe- or comma-delimited list of functions, which are invoked in order. When this property is set, the functional beans are automatically chained at runtime." Maybe give that a try?

Comment: Hi @onobc, I think spring.cloud.function.definition can be applied when we have multiple function beans defined. Let me try that.

Comment: It seems like you need tight integration into the success or failure of the s3-consumer.
I would suggest you look at `org.springframework.cloud.fn.consumer.s3.AwsS3ConsumerConfiguration` that uses `org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.S3MessageHandler` to do the work. Then you can decide how or where you need to handle exceptions.